# Error connecting redis server for cache from a nodejs / graphQL application

Tags: node.js, redis, graphql, react-apollo

We are trying to build a nodejs/graphql application and are trying to integrate redis for cache. Our test environment is OSX, all servers are locally installed. 
This how our apollo engine configuration looks like.

```
const engine = new ApolloEngine({
      apiKey: '<apollo-engine-api-key>',
      origins: [{
        supportsBatch: true,
        requestTimeout: '60s',
      }],
      stores: [
        {
          name: 'acme-store',
          memcache: {
            url: ['http://127.0.0.1:6379/acme-store'],
            keyPrefix: 'acme'
          }
        }
      ],
      queryCache: {
        publicFullQueryStore: 'acme-store'
      },
    });
```

We are using apollo client in our client application. But when the query fires, we are getting an error as follows.

```
WARN[1332] Query not stored to query cache.              
error="error saving response to query cache: dial unix http://127.0.0.1:6379/acme-store: connect: no such file or directory"
```

Any pointers for solving this issue while learn more about graphql/redis integration?

Thanks,

Comment: It seems like this would try to connect to memcached, not Redis, since ApolloEngine calls it `memcache`. They have different protocols . Also, the URL should just be `http://127.0.0.1:6379`, unless you configured routing differently in a proxy. If so, have you tried connecting to Redis using `redis-cli`?

Comment: We realize our fault. Can you please point us to some example with memcached with apolloEngine

Comment: Their docs have a way to use memcached https://www.apollographql.com/docs/engine/caching.html. I am not familiar with this library